# Confused by div getting styles only when control is specified

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I've got the style below (the file is linked and the color shows - no linkage issues).

```
div.hazoo {
  background: aquamarine;
}
```

However, when I remove the controler's specification and only use the style as if I mean **any** control on the page, the color gets retarded back to the default black (we're talking navbar in Bootstraps's theme, under MVC). I've even tried without the dot in the beginning - same result, of course.

```
.hazoo {
  background: aquamarine; 
}
```

The markup is the very, very defaulty one from the top of the *_Layout.cshtml* file, as shown below.

```
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top hazoo">
  ...
  </div>
</body>
```

What am I missing? Or am I mistaken in the belief that the the style assignment can be done to a general component using that syntax? Based on my previous experience, I can but Bootstrap has surprised me a few time the last few weeks, so I'm full of respect for my ignorance (if it's got to do with it to begin with, I'm uncertain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> See [W3's selector specifity docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity)
>   and you should find out why in one case background-color is overwritten or not. there is no problem to increase a selector weight for a specific match

It is a matter of selector weight (specifity) or position within the style sheet

- twice a selector of same weight/specifity: last one updates the previous
- 2 or more selector of different weight/specifity: the one with the most weight/specifity updates others. **seems to be your case**

> W3C examples:

```
    *               /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> specificity =   0 */
    LI              /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> specificity =   1 */
    UL LI           /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> specificity =   2 */
    UL OL+LI        /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> specificity =   3 */
    H1 + *[REL=up]  /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> specificity =  11 */
    UL OL LI.red    /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> specificity =  13 */
    LI.red.level    /* a=0 b=2 c=1 -> specificity =  21 */
    #x34y           /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> specificity = 100 */
    #s12:not(FOO)   /* a=1 b=0 c=1 -> specificity = 101 */
```

Answer (score 0):

download bootstrap and go to *bootstrap.css* and change the color for the *navbar-inverse* there as i don't think bootstrap from outside will allow you to change the color.

Comment: For certain reasons I won't be able to change the inner stuff in Bootstrap. I have to rely on changing it from my own classes outside of Bootstrap. Also, please note that I **have already** changed the looks. The question isn't how to affect the looks but why I can't do that using the second syntax, while the one with div explicitly specified does work.